# How to highlight a specific number of cells in a range based on a user value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: 5 rows highlighted based on user input]

I am trying to highlight a specific number of rows based on user input. Attached is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. The user would input a number in D1, in this case the user entered 5, and the first 5 rows would be highlighted in columns A&B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional formatting with a rule that uses a formula. The following formula has been applied to cells A1 to B 25. Note the placement of the $ signs. It has meaning and is important.

```
=ROW(A1)<=$D$1
```

[image]